# Jquery appendTo without losing focus

Tags: jquery, append, focus, lostfocus

I want to move an `li` element inside previous sibiling `li` when `tab` key is pressed keeping focus on it. But when I am moving, it is losing focus and executing `focusout` on the element.

```
    .bind("keydown", function(e) {
        var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which; 

        if (keyCode == 9) {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log('Tab pressed: moving it');
            $(this).appendTo($(this).prev());

            return false; // ignore default event
        }})
       .focusout(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();

        console.log('focusout');
        if(isEmpty($(this)) && $(this).siblings().size() != 0)
        {
            $(this).remove();
        }
        return false;
    })
```

Please suggest some solution to move element without losing focus.

Comment: You can't append an `<li>` to another `<li>` ... it's not valid html. Also you will need to unbind then bind again the `focusout` and manually trigger `focus`. Provide a [mcve]

Comment: Why not? Its working.

Comment: Because it's not valid.... might be working in browser you are using ... and it probably isn't being placed where you think it is, or it won't do same across all browsers. There are basic rules for where certain tags are allowed or not allowed

Comment: I am using node which uses chromium where its working.

Comment: Read it for yourself then https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li

Comment: @charlietfl you may be right but actually what you are suggesting is not causing me any problem. I will keep that in mind as further improvements. The major obstruction is what I have mentioned above. I tried searching but could not find any solution.

Comment: I explained what is needed above . Unbind focusout -> append -> trigger focus -> bind focusout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not jquery method to do it as I could find. Its to be done manually as mentioned by https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175966/charlietfl in comments.

```
Unbind focusout -> append -> trigger focus -> bind focusout
```

Unbind is to be done because in my code I am removing the element on which has already been appended elsewhere, so javascript was breaking.